# How to insert node at given index of a linked list

Tags: go, data-structures, linked-list

I am implementing the Linked List data structure with Go.

This method is supposed to insert the node by the given index.

**However, this only works properly when given an index number of 0.**

I have been reading and drawing to figure out the bug, but I could not find it.

If someone can give an insight, or approach to figure out this bug, I would appreciate it.

**What does your 'insertAt()' logic look like?**

1. if given index was invalid, print error message, and finish execution ***[works as expected]***
2. if given index was 0, push the node as a head node of the Linked list ***[works as expected]***
3. insert a new node to the given index number in linked list. ***[does NOT work as expected]***

*Below is the logic for (3), which does not work properly.*

> ->if the given index was valid and greater than 0, 
>   ->iterate the linked list until the iteration reaches index of (given index - 1)
>   ->Point the new node to the node in given index, 
>   ->Make the previous node to point to the new Node.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world.")

    ll := &LinkedList{
        head:   nil,
        tail:   nil,
        length: 1,
    }

    ll.push(11)
    ll.push(12)
    ll.insertAt(1, 50)

    var testNode = ll.head
    for testNode != nil {                         // This prints, 
        fmt.Println(testNode)                     // &{12 0xc000010200} &{11 <nil>}
        testNode = testNode.next                  // But it should be
    }                                          // &{12 0xc000010200} &{50 memoryaddress} &{11 <nil>}
}

// Node is an object holding its value and the memory address of next node
type Node struct {
    value int
    next  *Node
}

// LinkedList is a list of Node
type LinkedList struct {
    head   *Node
    tail   *Node
    length int
}

// Insert node at a given index
func (ll *LinkedList) insertAt(index, data int) {
    if index < 0 || index > ll.length {
        fmt.Println("invalid index")
    } else if index == 0 {
        newNode := &Node{
            value: data,
            next:  ll.head,
        }
        ll.head = newNode
        ll.length++
    } else {
        newNode := &Node{
            value: data,
            next:  nil,
        }
        counter := 0
        currentNode := ll.head
        var previousNode Node

        // we want to stop iteration at (index - 1)th position
        for counter < index {
            previousNode := currentNode
            currentNode = previousNode.next
            counter++
        }

        newNode.next = currentNode
        previousNode.next = newNode
        ll.length++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the implementation:

First: `previousNode` must be `var previousNode *Node` instead of `Node`.

Second: you are redeclaring `previousNode` in the for loop. Because of that, you never really set the pointer for the previous node. Use `previousNode=currentNode`, not :=

Comment: Thank you! The reason why `var previousNode *Node` should be the `pointer of type Node` instead of `the type Node`, is because we are handling `pointer to Node` in the Linked List. Am I correct?

Comment: Also, why does `previousNode := currentNode` always assign the copy of `currentNode` which is `ll.head`? The value of `currentNode` is always updated in the for a loop. I thought it would be the same as doing `previousNode = currentNode`

Comment: It is a pointer because you want to change the node in the list, not a copy of it.

Comment: The for-loop works fine, previousNode (which is a *Node) and currentNode move forward. When the loop terminates, previousNode set in the loop is forgotten, and you set the `next` field in `previousNode`, which is an uninitialized Node (not pointer).

Comment: Why is `previousNode set in the loop is forgotten` after the for loop? The variable, `previousNode` outside the for loop holds the same variable name, and it should be referencing the variable inside the for loop, right?

Comment: No, you redeclared `previousNode` in the loop. They are two different variables.

Comment: How is declaring two different variables with same variable name possible?

Comment: You can redefine a variable with the same name in a different scope: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Comment: Thanks, although your initial answer lacks details, I have accepted your answer, because you have provided an explanation while I asked you in the thread.